# How do I turn dataframe#1 into something i can properly graph, like dataframe#2?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe, based on data i pulled from my database:

| date | event_type | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-10 | page_view | 3 |
| 2022-05-11 | cart_add | 2 |
| 2022-05-11 | page_view | 2 |
| 2022-05-12 | cart_add | 1 |
| 2022-05-12 | cart_remove | 1 |
| 2022-05-12 | page_view | 2 |
| 2022-05-13 | cart_remove | 2 |
| 2022-05-13 | page_view | 1 |
| 2022-05-14 | cart_add | 2 |
| 2022-05-14 | page_view | 5 |

Basically I am tracking 3 things on my website:

1. when a user views a product page
2. when a user adds a product to their cart
3. when a user removes a product from their cart

I'm tracking how often each of these events happens in a day and I want to then graph them all on a single line chart. In order to do that, I think I need to make it look something more like this:

| date | page_views | cart_adds | cart_removes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-10 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-05-11 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 2022-05-12 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022-05-13 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 2022-05-14 | 5 | 2 | 0 |

I am very new to pandas and not even sure if this library is what I should be using. So forgive my cluelessness, but how do I make dataframe1 look like dataframe2?

Comment: Pandas is a good resource for this type of thing, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.pivot(columns='event_type', index='date').fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
              count                      
event_type cart_add cart_remove page_view
date                                     
2022-05-10      0.0         0.0       3.0
2022-05-11      2.0         0.0       2.0
2022-05-12      1.0         1.0       2.0
2022-05-13      0.0         2.0       1.0
2022-05-14      2.0         0.0       5.0
```

Comment: To pretty it up a bit you could add `.droplevel(0,axis=1).rename_axis('', axis=1)`